# Por que no me funciona mi mensaje Toastr?

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
public function store(AmortizacionStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $amorti = new Amortizacion;
        $amorti->id_cliente = $request->input('idcliente');
        $amorti->id_fac_enc = $request->input('nofac');
        $amorti->cantidad = $request->input('cantidad');
        $amorti->saldo = $request->input('saldo')-$request->input('cantidad');
        $amorti->save();
        toastr()->success('Amortizacion Realizada con Exito', 'Hola', ['timeOut' => 3000, 'progressBar' => true]);
        sleep(3);
        return redirect()->action('AmortizacionController@index');
    }
```

En el providers ya coloque la linea indicada:

```
Yoeunes\Toastr\ToastrServiceProvider::class,
```

Pero no me aparece nada, incluso si no le coloco muchas opciones en la funcion toast no me aparece nada, como puedo solucionarlo?